# Can't make API call mail.Send in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine

I know it's been asked lots of times, but I can't find an answer after doing my research.

I'm writing a REST api, and when users do a POST call, it will send an email to users

My methods:

```
public static void send(){
     String body = new StringBuilder()
            .append("Token: ")
            .append("12345")
            .append("\n")
            .append("Expiry Date: ")
            .append("2018")
            .toString();
    MailContent mailContent = new MailContent().subject("Token").body(body);
    sendEmail(mailContent);
 }

public static void sendEmail(mailContent){
    UserCredential userCredential = new UserCredential("username","password");
    String userName = userCredential.getUserName();
    String password = userCredential.getPassword();
    String recipient = mailContent.getRecipient();
    String subject = mailContent.getSubject();
    String body = mailContent.getBody();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new WebRequestException(new MessageKey(
                HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR,
                MessageKey.MessageKeyTags.RUN_TIME_ERROR,
                e.getMessage()
        ));
    }
```

it returned error:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call mail.Send in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:112) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:65) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.doSend(MailServiceImpl.java:103) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:33) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:232) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.66.jar:na]
at com.example.SpringBoot.AuthREST.AuthController.sendEmail(AuthController.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.SpringBoot.AuthREST.AuthController.sendEmail(AuthController.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.SpringBoot.AuthREST.AuthController.getToken(AuthController.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

I don't know if Tomcat is causing problem... It sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't.

Thanks for the help!